# execute process task python SSIS The process exit code was "2" while the expected was "0" on visual studio 2019

Tags: python, visual-studio, ssis

you gurus! I'm just to try to run a package that has some adicional taks, but the error is on the EXECUTE TASK PROCESS, I'm trying to run this simple code:

```
import win32com.client as win32
fname = "D:\VISTAS Custodia\Webcontrol_DITOv1"
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fname)

wb.SaveAs(fname+"", FileFormat = 51)    #FileFormat = 51 is for .xlsx extension
wb.Close()                               #FileFormat = 56 is for .xls extension
excel.Application.Quit()
```

And the execute task process parameters are:

[image]

I want to know what I'm doing wrong with this process :(

On visual Studio code and CMD runs perfectly

Thanks you all!!

Comment: If I were a guessing man, I'd assume that you have a bit mismatch (Project Properties, Debugging -> Run64BitRuntime {toggle False}). The next probable error will be running this on a server and it will have a reference to your folder path and a lack of permissions.  Define 2 SSIS variables of type string and wire them up to StandardOutputVariable and StandardErrorVariable and then inspect the values after the Execute Process Task has completed - perhaps there will be additional data there

Comment: Otherwise, I would rethink your approach wholesale. Conceptually, are you converting a .XLS to .XLSX via the Office interface. However, invoking the python interpreter to then interact with the workbook is an odd fit. I would expect to see those same commands in an Script Task written as C#/VB.NET  That would at least provide you an opportunity to debug and natively handle errors.